# How to link OIS?

Tags: header-files, dynamic-linking, archlinux

I've been searching and searching for the method to link OIS with my application. Unfortunately, I've been having issues finding anything. `-lois` just gives me errors, unfortunately.

**Question**

I need to know the proper header file for `OIS`, along with the right lib flag used to link it.

**Other info**

I'm running Arch Linux, got the package from their repos (with pacman, not yaourt), and haven't been able to link anything. Running `locate` in bash doesn't really give me much, either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

Found out that the proper way to link `OIS` is via `-lOIS`. As far as the proper header file, I have yet to find it.

**Edit**

Depending on the user's configuration, the proper header file should be either of the following:

`OIS.h` or `OIS/OIS.h`.

Also, a good reference:

http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/Using+OIS